# Managing multiple codebases with feature flags from a single git repository

Tags: git, repository, multiple-instances

I have a problem in which I have to manage multiple instances of the same code base (besides some configuration files) from 1 git repository. I would like to be able to push changes from the master branch of 1 main repository (think of it as a base application), and then update these same changes on the master branch of a different repository (which is the base application, with some features turned off).

This can be thought of as the digram below:

```
/BASE APPLICATION
--/BASE APPLICATION (1 feature turned off)
--/BASE APPLICATION (2 features turned off)
```

The base application git repository is the main source of truth. This would allow me to push bug fixes and enhancements all the way down to the repositories which are connected to the base repository. The only difference about the repositories which are connected the base application is that some features are turned on and off. The configuration files are used to turn the features on and off (feature flagging).

I am assuming this is a very common problem in software development, however I haven't seem to find a good solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I would set it up -

have all three config file in the same repo

and control which file gets picked with an environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Supporting many versions of the same code and issuing bug fixes to all of them is indeed a common problem. If the only difference is configuration then I would keep different configs together and I would add some mechanism to choose one of them, either during deployment by copying only one of them (e.g. in RPM spec) or based on environment variable.

If changes between versions are more complex a solution is to use different branches and some propagation mechanism, either by hooks or by external tool (I used dedicated self-written *monkey* process for it).

I can also imagine a solution with *git submodules*. Base Application may be one git project. Application 1 and Applicatin 2 are different branches of other git project having both Base Application a git submodule. Read about submodules in the web, e.g [here](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)

Comment: Thank-you for the information. I think the environment variables solution is what is required for this project.